# error with PDO connection in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i have PHP Version 5.2.8 on my windows 2003 server, i am trying to connect with database

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_pass);
```

but when i use this statement i got following error

```
   Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'
 in bin\db.php:14 Stack trace: #0 bin\db.php(14): 
PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '123') #1 
main.php(4): include_once('C:\Inetpub\wwwr...') #2
 {main} thrown in bin\db.php on line 14
```

how can i fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDOException “could not find driver”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)

Comment: i check this, but this also did't work...

Answer (score 2):

You must remove the ; on this line in php.ini :

```
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

Comment: i check already this before posting question , its without ;  and also i have php_pdo_mysql.dll in ext directory... but in my php_info it shows like this...   PDO drivers  sqlite2

Comment: Have you restarted the web server? Maybe it doesn't use the these settings yet...

Comment: are you sure you're editing the php.ini that your script is actually using?  You can check that with phpinfo()

Answer (score 0):

If you're upgrading PHP, be sure to check your environment variable information, especially your `PATH, and reboot if you change it.

I was using a `php.ini` file from a different directory. As Sebastian Grignoli suggests, check your `phpinfo()` results for the location of the `php.ini` it's using.