# PDO connection works from command line, but not through Apache?

Tags: php, mysql, connection, pdo

I have a very simple test script:

```
<?php

$DSN = "mysql:host=db.example.edu;port=3306;dbname=search_data";

try {
    $DB = new PDO($DSN, "username", "super-secret-password!");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    print "Could not connect to database, rawr. :-(";
    exit;
}

$SQL = "SELECT phrase FROM search ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10";

foreach ($DB->query($SQL) as $row) {
    print $row['phrase']."\n";
}

?>
```

When I execute this script from the command line, it works perfectly:

```
$ php test.php
corporal punishment
Stretches
voluntary agencies and the resettlement of refugees
music and learning
Nike Tiger Woods Scandal
Hermeneia
PSYCHINFO
anthony bourdain
Black-White Couples and their Social Worlds
colonization, hodge
```

But when I access the exact same script through my web browser, it says:

```
Could not connect to database, rawr. :-(
```

I've tried `var_dump` on the error, and the message is: "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db.example.edu' (13)".

This is puzzling.  It's the exact same script on the exact same server -- why does it work when I execute it from the command line, but fail when Apache executes it?

Comment: Is this a Linux server? Is it Red Hat or CentOS running SELinux? If so, you may need to enable the SELinux booleans `httpd_can_network_connect` and `httpd_can_network_connect_db` to allow Apache to establish connections to a remote database host.

Comment: more information about this error (13 = permission denied) is here: http://www.filonov.com/blog/2009/08/07/sqlstatehy000-2003-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-13/

Comment: @Michael Yes, it is a RHEL 6.1 server, and a shiny new one at that. Also, @thetaiko -- that worked!  It was SELinux blocking the connection, and running `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1` as root fixed it.  If you want to post that as an answer, I'll happily accept and upvote.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If this is a Red Hat-derived distribution (RHEL, CentOS, Fedora, ScientificLinux) running SELinux (or any non Red Hat derivative using SELinux), the default policy setting at time of this writing is to prohibit Apache from making external connections to other servers or databases. As root, you must enable the following two SELinux booleans.  Use the `-P` option to persist the change across a reboot.

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db=1
```

Note that `httpd_can_network_connect` may not be necessary. Try it first turning on only `httpd_can_network_connect_db`.

Comment: Thanks! The `httpd_can_network_connect` line wasn't necessary in my case, just the `httpd_can_network_connect_db` line.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue but different cause here

My **solution was just a simple `apt-get install php-mysql`** away

Be sure to **check for pdo_mysql in your phpinfo()**

Found it on this post : [PDOException “could not find driver”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver/40344563#40344563)

I wonder why CLI worked in such conditions O_o  Maybe something installed incorrectly, or got overriden ?  Well, now, it works fine !

Comment: Care to explain instead of just downvoting ?  I still got no idea why it worked in CLI and not through Apache.  If I missed something obvious, please, just tell us WHAT.
I posted my solution because it *actually solved my problem*, and might help others.  If I did something completely wrong, enlight us please.

Comment: Related to Sybase connection: on Ubuntu 18 I've reinstalled `php-sybase` package (php 7.2); on CentOS 7 I've reinstalled `php74-php-pdo-dblib` package (php 7.4). After this, restarted Apache on both machines and now connection is possible from my web app. Note CentOS machine has SElinux disabled, so setsebool command suggested in other answer did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for PHP ftp ftp_connect and had to set the

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
```

It's confusing because other things like `fil_get_contents` and curl work through PHP and apache just fine before setting that.

Answer (score 0):

In addition the using the above accepted answer

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db=1
```

I had to also change the security context of a file that `httpd` was trying to access.

A php script run through apache was trying to access a certificate file that was outside the normal document root of `httpd`. Changing the file permissions to allow httpd access was not enough to allow httpd access to that file. I had to change to security context as well, so before the change:

```
[admin]$ ls -Z ../../certs/rds-ca-2015-root-us-east-1-BUNDLE.pem 
-rw-r--r--. admin apache unconfined_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 ../../certs/rds-ca-2015-root-us-east-1-BUNDLE.pem
```

Change context using:

````
sudo chcon -v --type=httpd_sys_content_t ../../certs/rds-ca-2015-root-us-east-1-BUNDLE.pem```
````

to get:

```
[admin]$ ls -Z ../../certs/rds-ca-2015-root-us-east-1-BUNDLE.pem 
-rw-r--r--. admin apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 ../../certs/rds-ca-2015-root-us-east-1-BUNDLE.pem
```

Now all is good. A good resource to look at is `/var/log/audit/audit.log` and pay close attention to errors. In my case the error that pointed to the direction of a resolution was:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1509047616.042:4049): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=17096 comm="httpd" name="rds-ca-2015-root-us-east-1-BUNDLE.pem" dev="xvdb" ino=262146 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 tclass=file
```