# PHP: Unable to run the script from browser, but works fine when executed from linux terminal

Tags: php, mysql, linux, pdo

I am trying to connect to a remote mysql server using PDO php script. Script is working fine when run from the terminal.I am able to connect to the remote mysql database.

```
function db_connect($host, $username, $password, $db_name){
global $conn;
try{
    $conn =  new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name", $username, $password);
    $conn -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "success";
}

catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

But when I run this php script from browser, I got following error-

```
ERROR:SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server
```

First I though it is because I am running the script from root user.
But I tested it with a test user and it still runs from terminal but not from the browser.
I am also able to connect to the database from mysql workbench.
I don't know the cause. Please suggest some solution.

Comment: some code related to db connection will be helpful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139451/pdo-connection-works-from-command-line-but-not-through-apache