# PDO - 3D000 No database selected

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I wanted to create a PDO mysql connection. But the execute() function returns false and the errorInfo() returns "No database selected!". But I selected a database.

This is my code:

```
    $array = array("db" => "blogscript", "host" => "localhost", "user" => "root", "pass" => "");

    $db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=' . $array['db'] . ';host=' . $array['host'] . '', $array['user'], $array['pass']);

    $statement = $db->prepare('
        SELECT *
          FROM pages
    ');

    $r = $statement->execute();
    if ($r === false) {
        return $statement->errorInfo();
    }
```

The database "blogscript" existst.

Comment: Bit of a stab in the dark, but have you tried the connection string with the host first, then the dbname? EDIT: Ignore that, works OK on my db with your code.

Comment: <?php
$db = new PDO('dblib:host=your_hostname;dbname=your_db;charset=UTF-8', $user, $pass);
?>

refer: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: @Coder anonymous Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'

Comment: The error tells you what the issue is. You don't appear to have the pdo_mysql module enabled / installed.

Comment: Here is the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2852748/1687983

Comment: @JonStirling nope. The drivers are installed. I used phpinfo() to check it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hard coding the connection with  `database & host` in this order

```
$db = new PDO('dbname=blogscrip;mysql:host=localhost', root, pass);
```

Throws exception  `could not find driver`

in the order in  [**documentation**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blogscript', root, pass);
```

Works

Change the order to `host & database`

Comment: I made it like you said but there is the same error: `3D000 - 1046 - No database selected!`.

Comment: Glad to help.I find if you try to do things by the manual first before you try to experimentand and then add things incrementally.This way you know where the errors are occuring