# MySql connection

Tags: php, mysql

```
    <?php
// connect to MySQL
 $connect = new PDO ("localhost", "username", "")
 or die ( "Hey loser, check your server connection");

 // make sure we`re using the right database 
 mysql_select_db ( "moviesite");

 // insert data into "movie" table
 $insert= "INSERT INTO movie (movie_id, movie_name, movie_type,
    movie_year, movie leadactor, movie_director)".
"VALUES (1, 'Bruce Almighty', 5 , 2003, 1, 2), " .
"(2, 'Office Space', 5, 1999, 5, 6),".
"(3, 'Grand Canyon', 2, 1991, 4, 3)";
$results = mysql_query($insert)
or die (mysql_error());

// insert data into "movietype" table
$type = "INSERT INTO movietype (movietype_id, movietype_label) ".
"VALUES (1, 'Sci Fi'), " .
"(2, 'Drama'), " . 
"(3, 'Adventure'),".
"(4, 'War'),".
"(5,'Comedy'),".
"(6, 'Horror'),".
"(7,'Action'),".
"(8,'Kids')";
$results = mysql_query($type)
or die (mysql_error());
// insert data into "people" table
$people = "INSERT INTO people (people_id, people_fullname, " .
    "people_isactor, people_isdirector) " . 
"VALUES (1, 'Jim Carrey', 1, 0), " . 
"(2, 'Tom Shadyac', 0, 1), " .
"(3, 'Lawrence Kasdan', 0, 1) , " .
"(4, 'Kevin Kline', 1, 0), " .
"(5, 'Ron Livingston', 1, 0), " .
"(6, 'Mike Judge', 0, 1)"; 
$results = mysql_query($people)
or die (mysql_error());
echo "Data inserted succsesfully!";
?>
```

Hey guys. I have a problem. When i run this code, i get this error:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException'
```

with message

```
'invalid data source name' in C:\wamp\www\moviedata.php on line 3 ( ! ) PDOException: invalid data source name in C:\wamp\www\moviedata.php on line 3
```

If someone can help me fix this , i will be thankful .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught exception 'PDOException' message 'invalid data source name'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19740829/uncaught-exception-pdoexception-message-invalid-data-source-name)

Comment: The exception tells you what the problem is: 'invalid data source name'. The first argument to the PDO constructor must be a valid DSN, which 'localhost' is not. Read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) about DSNs.

Comment: Maybe a dup, but this question does not seem to be overriding PDO, maybe he is facing a different problem.

Comment: Also, if you are trying to convert this from mysql to pdo, you need to convert it all. You cannot have part of your code use pdo and part use mysql.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling

```
mysql_select_db ( "moviesite");
```

But that is not part of PDO, it is part of MySQL.

You should be doing:

```
$DB_HOST = "";
$DB_NAME = "";
$DB_PASS = "";
$DB_PORT = 3306;
$DB_USER = "";

$dsn = "mysql:host=" . $DB_HOST . ";port=" . $DB_PORT . ";dbname=" . $DB_NAME . ";charset=utf8";

$db_connection = new PDO($dsn, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);
```

Comment: Thanks man... You just saved my school project :p

Answer (score 2):

Don't mix mysql_* functions and PDO.
Check the syntax of the [PDO_MySQL DSN](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php).

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=moviesite;charset=utf8', 'username', '', array(
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=>false,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY=>false,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
));

$pdo->exec("
    INSERT INTO movie
        (movie_id, movie_name, movie_type, movie_year, movie leadactor, movie_director)
    VALUES
        (1, 'Bruce Almighty', 5 , 2003, 1, 2),
        (2, 'Office Space', 5, 1999, 5, 6),
        (3, 'Grand Canyon', 2, 1991, 4, 3)
");
// and so on and on
```