# Internal Server Error when executing basic SQL statement

Tags: php, database, symfony

I am working on my local wamp server and trying to retrieve data from a phpMyAdmin. But i am getting an error.

> could not find driver 500 Internal Server Error - PDOException

my routing.yml

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: www.example.com
    database_port: null
    database_name: mydb
    database_user: myuser
    database_password: mypass
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: www.example.com
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    locale: en
    secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
    database_path: null
```

my controller

```
$connection = $this->get("database_connection");
$statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
$statement->execute();
$tabs = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Comment: check your php.ini whether pdo_mysql is uncommented

Comment: Are you trying to use Doctrine DBAL connection? 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/dbal.html

`public function indexAction()
    {
        $conn = $this->get('database_connection');
        $users = $conn->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM users');

        // ...
    }`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's a driver issue. You need to make sure that your PHP environment has loaded `pdo_mysql`. For more info, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver).

Comment: it has already installed. Thats why i asked the question again. The post you mention does not include my answer.

Comment: How are you verifying that it's installed? It's not enough for it to be on the system -- it must be configured in php.ini. A good way of checking is running phpinfo() (http://php.net/phpinfo).

Comment: Specifically, when you're running phpinfo(), does it actually list MySQL support under PDO? It may be that you have some base PDO library, but not the MySQL version that you need.