# Can't find MySQL driver anymore (Linux)

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, pdo

Today some of my packages in Ubuntu was upgraded automatically, and I didn't think of what was actually going on.

Ever since the update, my local dev-environment doesn't work anymore. First of by not working was mod_rewrite which I had to enable again using a2enmod. But now I've run into an issue that I can't seem to resolve. My application can't seem to find the PDO MySQL driver. When running the application, I get the error `failed to open the DB connection: could not find driver`.

This is strange, since if I check the `phpinfo()` the PDO drivers do support MySQL, and the socket path is a valid path.

pdo_mysql client API version is 5.5.35 according to php info.

**PHP5**: 5.5.3
**MySQL**: 5.5.35

Connectionstring

```
mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=MyDB;port=3306
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDOException “could not find driver”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)

Comment: The problem in the "duplicate" was that the module pdo_mysql wasn't enabled. I have that module enabled, and it's showing up in phpinfo.

Comment: Show us code that you use to connect to DB. Also triple-check that you have `pdo_mysql` module enabled. `php5-mysql` AFAIR is not the package you should be looking at.

Comment: I am using the Yii framework, where the models uses a class called CDbConnection, which utilizes PDO to connect to the DB defined in my configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP MySQL driver (`mysql.so`/`mysqli.so`) and the PHP PDO MySQL driver (`pdo_mysql.so`) are two *separate* modules. You need both of them for PDO functionality with MySQL.

It is quite possible that one of them is missing or of an incompatible version - I do not have an Ubuntu system at hand, but on my RPM-based Linux distribution there is a separate package for each module (`php-mysql`/`php-mysqli` and `php-pdo_mysql`). I also expect PDO to be using the newer `mysqli.so` driver, rather than the obsolete `mysql.so` one, so you should verify that one is installed as well.

Comment: I checked the extensions path and both of them is available. mysqli as well.

Comment: Available and enabled?

Comment: @AntonGildebrand: what about `phpinfo()`?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install -y php5-mysql php5 mysql-client
```

This should automatically restart your apache if any of the dependencies aren't installed.

Try using vagrant.
Dependencies can be isolated, upgraded and downgraded when you like.

[Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/)

Comment: Running this shows me that everything already is up to date. Nothing is done.

Comment: Thats strange because you say the path is also displayed in your phpinfo().