# Why do I get a whitescreen when logging in to my PHP CMS? Without passwords this time

Tags: php, mysql

I am in the process of creating a simple PHP-CMS. I have of course also created a simple login Form, which as you can see uses an SQL query to check if the Username and Password that are typed in match, etc.

This worked fine for months now until recently I changed something in this file (I cannot remember what: Sorry) and now all I get when I enter the correct username/password is a whitescreen! I have enabled errorreporting in PHP but I get nothing

Can someone help me/check my code for the error?

Many thanks in advance!

this here is the PHP loginpanel.php file.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ob_start();

if(isset($_POST["SubmitBtn"]))
{
 $username = $_POST["Name"];
 $password = $_POST["Pass"];
 $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=fdb6.awardspace.net;dbname=1645626_cms","***","****");
 $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM T_Users WHERE Username = :username AND Password = :password");
 $query->bindParam(":username", $username);
 $query->bindParam(":password", $password);
 $query->execute();

  // geneste if voor het inloggen indien aan de voorwaarde hierboven voldaan word+countdown/welkomstbericht
  if($result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
  {
  echo "Welcome " .$result->Username. "!";
  echo '<p>You will be logged in in 5 seconds.</p>';
  session_start();
  $_SESSION["Name"] = $username;
  header("Location:http://stuff.romulus310ftp.dx.am/CMS/login/adminpanel.php");
  }
  else
  {
  echo "You entered the wrong password or username. Please try again.";
  }
}

// ifje voor de registratie-countdown
if (isset($_POST["RegistrateBtn"]))
{
echo '<p>You will be redirected in 5 seconds.</p>';
header("Location:http://stuff.romulus310ftp.dx.am/CMS/login/registrationpanel.php");
}

?>
```

And this is its' HTML

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>CMS by Romulus</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css">
 </head>

 <body>
   <form action="#" method="post" class="form">
        Name: <input type="text" name="Name">
    </br>
         Passw: <input type="password" name="Pass">
    </br>
              <input type="submit" value="Enter" name="SubmitBtn">
            <input type="submit" value="Register" name="RegistrateBtn">         
   </form>

  </body>   
</html>
```

EDIT: I found out I get the error "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'" which according to a friend of mine means there is a problem at my host. Is this true?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making a test page and outputting phpinfo()

You should be able to see whether PDO is installed there

Comment: PDO is installed, it shows these as the enabled drivers: sqlite, sqlite 2. Is that good or bad? ;)

Comment: Depends, are you trying to connect to a sqlite database? You're probably looking for the mysql or postgres driver?

Comment: I am indeed using an MySQL-DB and those drivers aren't there.. should I contact my host about this? Everything worked fine for me until today.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your `PDO` connection in a try / catch block:

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO(...)
    //queries, etc.
}

catch(PDOException $ex) {
    echo(ex->getMessage());
}
```

It's possible that your hostname is wrong, your username, your password, or even your query. The `getMessage` method should help you track down which line is causing you problems.

EDIT: Judging by your update with the `PDO` error, I would suggest visiting [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver) to find out about enabling the MySQL PDO driver in your PHP installation.