# Could not find driver while migrating on Laravel 4 using XAMPP Server Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: php, pdo, laravel-4, xampp, database-migration

I have installed Laravel 4.1 everything worked just fine, but when I try to use migration it throws a PDO Exception saying:

> > [PDOException]
> >     could not find driver

I found many answers on StackOverFlow, but none of them solved my problem, unfortunately.

I have tried to enable pdo extension and pdo_mysql extension, but it says that pdo is already loaded. I have tried to reinstall PDO and PDO MySQL but nothing worked.

I am using XAMPP Server on a Ubuntu 64bit machine.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver Also, can you paste the phpinfo to your question as well?

Comment: the phpinfo is too big! What sections do you need me to tell you about?
I have pdo_mysql installed and I have it on my phpinfo as well!

Comment: See the configure commands if `--with-pdo-mysql` option exists. Then look for the subsection its value is (for eg. `mysqlnd`). Paste the contents under `PDO` and `pdo_mysql` sections.

Comment: Do you have the same exception in the app or does it happen only when you try to run the migrations ?

Comment: in both, in the app and while running migrations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is solved!

Steps:

1. Uninstall XAMPP
2. `apt-get update && apt-get install lamp-server^`
3. `apt-get autoremove apache2`
4. `apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common`
5. `apt-get autoremove && apt-get update && apt-get install php5-mysql && apt-get install pdo-mysql`
6. Install XAMPP

However, I had a new problem with running `php artisan` then I discovered that I had to run `/opt/lampp/bin/php artisan` instead of `php artisan`

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for simple solution, I had same issue & this worked for me..

When you run `php artisan` from terminal, you invoke `php5-cli` package.

To run artisan with XAMPP's php you need to use:

**`/opt/lampp/bin/php artisan migrate`**

But make sure your `/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini` is properly configured to enable pdo_mysql

Comment: It's actually what I did! If you check my answer you will find that. However, I had to reinstall XAMPP because I made some major changes in php.ini which caused it to get confused.

Comment: okay.. am merely pointing that the solution for raised problem doesn't need a re-installation :)