# Laravel/MySQL database connection

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I have an unusual problem with my Laravel 4.2 project connecting to MySQL database. This is my database.php

```
'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'database_name',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => '',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        )
```

I use XAMPP for Ubuntu.

First, I've created a database in phpMyAdmin. When I tried to run `php artisan migrate`, it gave me an error of `unknown database 'database_name'`. I thought it was silly since I've just created a database in phpMyAdmin. Then I tried creating a database through the command line and tried running the migration again. It worked. Tables were created under the database I specified when I run `show tables` in the command line. It seems to me that the Laravel project is connected to a different mysql server than the phpMyAdmin. Is that even possible? How can I solve this problem?

I've been trying to solve this for hours but still, no luck. Hope someone can help me with my problem.

Comment: Your command line, and consequently `artisan` are using the system version of MySQL - not the one provided by XAMMP. Have a look at this for a possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24533644/could-not-find-driver-while-migrating-on-laravel-4-using-xampp-server-linux-ubu

Comment: Thank you. I've finally figured out the problem. That solution helped a lot.

Comment: would you answer your own question with you fix to share it with others that may have the same issue @user3079254

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by following the solution in the link provided by Bulk. I just have to run `sudo /opt/lampp/bin/php artisan migrate` instead of the plain `php artisan migrate`. With this, `artisan` will use the MySQL version provided by XAMPP.