# PHP5 MySQL5 PDOException “could not find driver”

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-5.6, php-5.6

I have already tried the instructions mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver) but still couldn't resolve the issue.

System Specifications:

- Windows 7 Professional SP1 (x64)
- Apache 2.1.12 (x64)
- PHP 5.6.6 (x64)
- MySQL 5.6.22 (x64)

The following configurations are set as well:

```
extension_dir = "C:\Apache\php\ext"
....
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

---

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=customers", $user, $pass);
```

Unfortunately I am still having the exception, "PDOException: Could not find driver".

P.S/ I am new to PHP ;)

Comment: Is this your **real** and **full** code which you show us here, which produces this error?

Comment: @eggyal. I couldn't find php_pdo.dll inside ext folder.

Comment: @Rizer123. Since I am new to PHP, I am just trying out PDO. I omitted the variable assignments ($user and $pass) and try catch block for simplification purpose.

Comment: You're right, sorry.  `php_pdo.dll` was pre-PHP v5.3.

Comment: Have you restarted PHP/Apache since modifying `php.ini`?

Comment: Yup. I restart the server whenever I make changes to php.ini file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just removed the existing MySQL 5.6.22 and installed 5.6.23 -a different build. Now it is working fine but I am not sure what went down the road.