# PHP cli and PDOException

Tags: php, laravel, pdo, laravel-5

Im trying to run a very basic Laravel app on my localhost.

I have a simple postgre DB, which contains 3 data rows. I can query the items in razorSQL and get the results, so the DB is fine.

In phpStorm I start a web server using `php -S localhost:8888 -t public`

Web server starts fine. If I start the app I get the Laravel home screen.

Okay, then I change the home route to this. I get "Hello World" displayed.

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    $data = "Hello World";
    return $data;
});
```

But when I do this

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    $data = \DB::table('posts')->get();
    return $data;
});
```

I get...

[image]

Do phpStorm support PDO or is ther some plugin that I need?

**UPDATE**

```
Route::get('/', function(){
//            $data = \DB::table('posts')->get();
    $data = phpinfo();
    return $data;
});
```

php.ini location
[image]

php.ini
[image]

So PDO is enabled in php.ini. This is what I dont get. And yes I am new to PHP.

here is the PDO snip from `phpInfo()` - PS, yes I did restart wamp after the change. I just dont understand why `pdo_pgsql` is not appearing/working

[image]

Its also active in the Dropdown `php extensions`
[image]

Comment: What this error has to do with PhpStorm (except the fact that you are using PhpStorm to write your code)? So far it looks like you have not enabled PDO driver/extension for Posgre in your php.ini.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDOException “could not find driver”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)

Comment: Im asking about phpStorm, as this is where I started the web server. 
So php.ini in porsgre. Where is this file located in the postgre file structure?

Comment: *"Im asking about phpStorm, as this is where I started the web server."* And? This error is generated by PHP itself and not by PhpStorm. *"Where is this file located in the postgre file structure?"*  Are you new to PHP? If yes then just say so. Because php.ini is part of PHP and not Postgre.

Comment: How did you get that `phpinfo()` output? It has to be done via the same way as your actual code (which means -- call it in your Laravel app) as it's possible that you have 2 different `php.ini` for CLI and Apache (the way how you started Laravel's web server is considered CLI)

Comment: @LazyOne, please elaborate. You tell me what things are supposed to be, but you dont go into much detail. Please can you just elaborate on this. I ran phpInfo() from laravel and that is what it came up with. Is that not the same php.ini file that Laravel uses then?

Comment: If it's run from Laravel then it's the same. If that extension was enabled .. then it supposed to work (although I should not be considered as "pro" in this particular case as I'm not using Postgre myself -- only MySQL, SQL Server and SQLite (sometimes)). If you have enabled that extension just now -- make sure that you have restarted your web server (no `php.exe` or similar processes in Task Manager). Also -- you should have separate section with Postgre PDO current settings in `phpinfo()` output -- can you please list it as well?

Comment: As you can see -- the PDO driver for Postgre is not actually loaded. I suggest: 1) make sure that PHP logs errors into a log file 2) make sure that `display_startup_errors = On` in php.ini; 3) Try `php -i` in console -- it may provide more details. As it stands right now it could be that PDO driver for Postgre is unable to find some library which it needs to be able to communicate with actual Postgre DB server (had such kind of errors long time ago (3-5 years or so) with MySQL)

Comment: **FYI:** Please note that using `php -S localhost:8888 -t public` means that page (e.g. `http://localhost:8888/index.php`) will be served by PHP's own simple server directly and not by your Apache from WAMP.

Comment: @LazyOne. This "simple server". wont this also have a php.ini file then? Maybe I should opt for `homestead` instead, but I would like to solve this problem. Thanks for the heads-up though.

Comment: As I have stated in my 3rd comment -- it could be (not using WAMP myself). But you have said that you have captured `phpinfo()` using it .. so it should represent correct path to php.ini already . In any case: `php -i` in console and see what file it uses. P.S. I believe that `homestead` would be the best choice overall (as in this case it will be running in separate VM and not messing with your host OS (Windows))

Comment: Forget about WAMP and phpStorm, neither has anything to do with your problem. You are invoking php from the command line, you need to find out what php.ini is actually used (@LazyOne has already told you how to do that). Once you find that out, then all you need to do is what you would have done if you were editing WAMP's php.ini.

Comment: cant explain it, but its fixed. CLI and WAMP where using the same `php.ini` file anyways. If I learn more about `httpd.conf`, maybe I will understand in the future. Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finaly resoved it, but will use `HOMESTEAD` anyways, but here is the solution.

`WAMP` and `php CLI` where both using the same `php.ini file`.
But I came across this solution and it worked.

You just have to add this lines into the `httpd.conf`

> PHPIniDir "*Full path to your PHP directory*/"
>   Loadfile "*Full path to your PHP directory*/php5ts.dll"
>   Loadfile "*Full path to your PHP directory*/libpq.dll"
>   LoadModule php5_module "*Full path to your PHP directory*/php5apache2_4.dll"

save `httpd.conf`

> Exit WAMP

Then in `cmd` do

> `net stop dnscache`
>    `net start dnscache`

then

> Restart WAMP

So it looks like this in the end

```
#This was activated on 23/04/2015
LoadFile "H:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/php5ts.dll"
LoadFile "H:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/libpq.dll"
PHPIniDir h:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/
LoadModule php5_module "h:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/php5apache2_4.dll"
```