# Exception 'could not find driver' while migration in yii2

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

This my stack trace:

```
  Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'could not find driver'

in /opt/lampp/htdocs/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php:534

#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php(836): yii\db\Connection->open()
        #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php(823): yii\db\Connection->getMasterPdo()
        #2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php(208): yii\db\Connection->getSlavePdo()
        #3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php(816): yii\db\Command->prepare(true)
        #4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php(350): yii\db\Command->queryInternal('fetchAll', NULL)
        #5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/mysql/Schema.php(198): yii\db\Command->queryAll()
        #6 /opt/lampp/htdocs/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/mysql/Schema.php(97): yii\db\mysql\Schema->findColumns(Object(yii\db\TableSchema))
        #7 /opt/lampp/htdocs/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Schema.php(140): yii\db\mysql\Schema->loadTableSchema('migration')
        #8 /opt/lampp/htdocs/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/controllers/MigrateController.php(121): yii\db\Schema->getTableSchema('{{%migration}}', true)
        #9 /opt/lampp/htdocs/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/controllers/BaseMigrateController.php(610): yii\console\controllers\MigrateController->getMigrationHistory(NULL)
        #10 /opt/lampp/htdocs/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/controllers/BaseMigrateController.php(102): yii\console\controllers\BaseMigrateController->getNewMigrations()
        #11 [internal function]: yii\console\controllers\BaseMigrateController->actionUp(0)
        #12 /opt/lampp/htdocs/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(55): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
        #13 /opt/lampp/htdocs/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(151): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
        #14 /opt/lampp/htdocs/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Controller.php(91): yii\base\Controller->runAction('', Array)
        #15 /opt/lampp/htdocs/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(455): yii\console\Controller->runAction('', Array)
        #16 /opt/lampp/htdocs/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(161): yii\base\Module->runAction('migrate', Array)
        #17 /opt/lampp/htdocs/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(137): yii\console\Application->runAction('migrate', Array)
        #18 /opt/lampp/htdocs/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(375): yii\console\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\console\Request))
        #19 /opt/lampp/htdocs/advanced/yii(31): yii\base\Application->run()
        #20 {main}
```

I am new to yii2. I have added database name,username in `advaced/common/config/main-local.php`. Using xampp webserver and version of php is 5.6.8 and PDO is also enabled.

This is my db configuration.

```
'db' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yii2advanced',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDOException “could not find driver”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Found this on [Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-improved-basic-template/)

> "Most likely it is your system config. If you are using packages like
>   MAMP, XAMPP or other, you may need to change "localhost" to
>   "127.0.0.1" in your db.php configuration file. Also if you are on
>   Linux you may need to install some other additional packages like
>   php5-mysql and stuff like that."

Comment: Thank you, I am using ubuntu, installed php5-mysql and it worked after changing host name to ip address...

Comment: i am using windows XP, even i change to 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost still the same problem is exist, for your information i have PHP 7.0.2 Version in my system

Comment: I am using CentOS, using ip instead of localhost is not working for me.

Comment: @huuang simply run "sudo apt-get install php-mysql" in terminal

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar situation during Yii2 (Advanced) migration (Xampp in Ubuntu 14.04 and PHP)

This is the message i've got:

> Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'could not find driver'

So after googling and reading this thread and others I found out that could be the possible problem

the PHP extension "pdo_mysql" was disabled or not installed at all

and tried this at my terminal:

```
php -m
```

after realize that the module was not there...

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd php5-mysql
```

and after a quick install the service must be re-started...

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

....finally (retry migration)

```
php yii migrate
```

Migrated up successfully.

Hope you find it useful & work for others.

I found it at ask ubuntu but i'm unable to add a link or code, since this is my first post.

link: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/49450-error-on-migrate-command-advanced-yii2-app/

Answer (score 4):

In my case (on Ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysql  
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same error. Searching, I found a Brazilian comment regarding a similar problem caused because he had two different php version installed in his computer.

I checked the /opt/lampp/bin directory and I found two different php versions, one just plain "php" and the other "php-5.6.8", so I decided to run the second version, and it works!

test@pctest:~$ /opt/lampp/bin/php-5.6.8  /opt/lampp/htdocs/advanced/yii migrate

Answer (score 1):

in my case:

add `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` in php\php.ini

Answer (score 0):

I had same error, but instead of xampp I used Fedora 25 with Apache, for me 'dnf install -y php-mysqlnd' fixed this error, so you are probably missing extension.

Comment: This seems not an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. Also check this [what can I do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by changing PHP path like this

1. Go to "My Computer" right click and click "Properties"
2. Click "Advanced system settings"
3. Click "Environment Variables"
4. Find the "Path" in System variables, double click it.
5. Find your PHP Path or add it if you not have it yet, like "D:\xampp\php"
6. Click OK and restart your Apache server.
7. That's it, I can migrate db then.

Answer (score 0):

I re-configured php, adding this flag:

```
--with-pdo-mysql
```

I'm using LAMP, and this worked for me.