# could not find driver in wamp php after run

Tags: php, driver

am using following code to connect to database

```
//database credentials
define('DBHOST', 'localhost');
define('DBUSER', 'sanoj');
define('DBPASS', '123456');
define('DBNAME', 'test');

//application address
define('DIR', 'http://www.blogtom.com/');
define('SITEEMAIL', 'sanoj26692@gmail.com');

try {

    //create PDO connection 
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DBHOST . ";port=3306;dbname=" . DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $db->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8';");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    //show error
    echo '<p class="bg-danger">' . $e->getMessage() . '</p>';
    exit;
```

after i run my php file from **netbeans ide** i get nothing except this

```
could not find driver
```

i tried all method checking `php.ini` file

and even read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2852997/3836908 tofind some solution 
but cant find whats wrong

i used this code in PC it worked well but when i try this on my laptop i get this error how can i solve this problem

am using windows 64bit 
but previouly i used 32bit

Comment: The problem is that you're missing (or PHP - or NetBeans -  can't find) your MySQL JDBC driver.  I would recommend installing mysqlnd, the MySQL Native Driver: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/php-mysqlnd/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry for bad english!

Create a file named **info.php** with this content:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Save and put in your server root.
Access http://localhost/info.php
See what PDO Drivers are loaded (CTRL + F and type PDO drivers).
MySql PDO Driver need to be loaded like this:
[image: pdo mysql]

If you don't see mysql on PDO drivers, you should edit **php.ini** and add `extension=pdo_mysql.dll`
Restart your Apache and try again in **info.php**

PS: Certify that you have the **pdo_mysql.dll** in your PHP extensions folder.

Comment: The WAMP server seems Ok but I am getting the same error on PDO->_contruct();

Answer (score 1):

To anyone that don't know where is the extension folder.
Go to PHP.ini and search for: extension_dir
And how you can see in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CUuv.jpg), thats the path.