# php artisan migrate returns "PDO Exception could not find driver"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo

I'been trying to migrate in Laravel, however it returned the following error.

```
$ php artisan migrate

  [PDOException]
  could not find driver
```

I've check the several [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver), methiond with `PDOException could not find driver`, however  I have not solved the problem yet.
My development environment is following. Could you tell me how to solve the problem?

- OSX10.11
- PHP:5.5.31
- Laravel:5.2
- Mysql

The following is `.env` file.

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=SomeRandomString

DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=hoge_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=fuga

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

Comment: Sorry, It didn't solved my problem. This situation was Linux, but my situation is OSX. OSX doesn't have pdo_mysql.

Comment: That's the point, though. You need pdo_mysql. It is available for OSX. Your setup doesn't have it installed, which is why artisan is complaining. How you should install it depends on your specific setup.

Comment: Try composer install in the directory of your application.

Comment: @Siddharth I tried `composer install` on the application folder, but it has not solved the problem yet.