# How to install pdo driver in php docker image?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, docker

I am using as a base the [php docker container](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) with the tag:

```
php:5.6-apache
```

I linked it with a basic `mysql:5.6` image which I can reach at the host `mysql`. I created a DB, and filled a table with basic values.

Yet trying to access my app, I get:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
could not find driver' in /var/www/html/index.php:30 
Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: 
PDO->__construct('mysql:host=mysq...', 'root', 'root', Array) 
#1 [internal function]: Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo->connect(Array)
#2 /var/www/html/index.php(30): Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo-__construct(Array)
#3 [internal function]: {closure}()
#4 [internal function]: Phalcon\Di\Service->resolve(NULL, Object(Phalcon\Di\FactoryDefault))
#5 [internal function]: Phalcon\Di->get('db', NULL)
#6 [internal function]: Phalcon\Di->getShared('db')
#7 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Manager->_getConnection(Object(Reviews), NULL)
#8 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Manager->getReadConnection(Object(Reviews))
#9 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\Model->getReadConnection()
#10 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\Model\MetaData\Strategy\Introspection->getMetaData(Object(Reviews), Object(Phalcon\Di\FactoryDefault))
#11 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\Model\MetaData->_initialize(Object(Rev in /var/www/html/index.php on line 30
```

Hence, I thought that the php container was lacking the `php-mysql` component I installed via:

```
apt-get install php5-mysql
```

I also added a mysql.ini at:

```
cat /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/mysql.ini
; configuration for php MySQL module
; priority=20
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

If I `echo phpinfo();die` it tells me that:

```
Additional .ini files parsed:
    /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/mysql.ini,
    /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/phalcon.ini
```

Yet still, the error persists.

Furthermore, when running:

```
php -i|grep PDO
```

I get:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PDO
PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => sqlite
PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled
```

so it seems the mysql extension isn't even activated.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Investigating [a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver) it seems that the module isn't loaded.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

> The official repository of PHP has a script called `docker-php-ext-install` https://github.com/docker-library/php/tree/master/5.6

You forgot to install the extension needed to run the PDO.

Try do create a docker image like this:

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

# PHP extensions

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

Comment: If using only MySQL, you can remove the PostgreSQL `pdo_pgsql` extension, which has additional requirements for installation.

Comment: `RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql` also works with MariaDB

Comment: I had to also modify the php.ini file by adding `extension=pdo_mysql`

Answer (score 2):

If you need to work with php 8.1 and use pdo and pdo_mysql extensions, try this:

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm
WORKDIR /var/www/html
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
```

The pdo extension is installed by default and change the `WORKDIR` value according to your use case

Learn more on [PHP Official Docker image page](https://hub.docker.com/_/php?tab=description&page=1&name=8.0-rc-&ordering=last_updated)