# Run `docker-php-ext-install` FROM container other than php

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, php-extension

I have a problem with Docker (docker-compose). I want to install some PHP extensions using `docker-compose.yml`, but I am unable to do this, because my .yml has `FROM ubuntu` and not `FROM php`. Is there any way I can achieve or access the `docker-php-ext-install`?

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt -yqq update
RUN apt -yqq install nginx iputils-ping
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mbstring

WORKDIR /usr/local/src

COPY docker/nginx/dev.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/dev.conf
COPY docker/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

CMD ["nginx"]
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=1
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=mariadb
    links:
      - mariadb
  php:
    image: php:7.1.1-fpm
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - .:/dogopic
    links:
      - mariadb
  nginx:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/dogopic
    links:
      - php
```

#### Console output (fragment)

```
Step 5/9 : RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mbstring
 ---> Running in 445f8c82883d
/bin/sh: 1: docker-php-ext-install: not found
```

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527803/how-to-install-extension-for-php-via-docker-php-ext-install

Comment: I've looked at it before, but my problem isn't with extension dependencies, but with the thing, that docker-php-ext-install exists in `php` container

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## New solution

You need to create new Dockerfile for specific service, in this case `php`:

### `php/Dockerfile`

```
FROM php:7.1.1-fpm
RUN apt -yqq update
RUN apt -yqq install libxml2-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install xml
```

And then *link* to it in your `docker-compose.yml` file, just like this:

```
services:
  // other services
  php:
    build: ./php
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - .:/dogopic
    links:
      - mariadb
```

Please look at `build` parameter - it points to directory in which is that new Dockerfile located.

## Old solution

I walked around the problem. I've figured out that I can still run this `docker-php-ext-install` script using following command:

```
docker-compose exec <your-php-container> docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mbstring
```

And because of the convenience I've created this simple Batch file to simplify composing containers just to one command: `./docker.bat`

```
@ECHO OFF

docker-compose build
docker-compose exec php docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mbstring
docker-compose up
```

Comment: Actually, doing this on `docker-compose` smells like an anti-pattern.

Comment: Each RUN command adds a layer to the Docker image stack, so whenever possible, try and combine run commands. Pretty sure the docker-php-ext-install script builds and cleans up each time it runs. So if you can pass pdo_mysql and xml in a single call, that is a lot faster I believe.

Answer (score 17):

`docker-php-ext-install` is not some native docker functionality. If you read [php docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) page carefully, you will see, that it's just a script provided to make the installation process easy:

> We provide the helper scripts `docker-php-ext-configure`, `docker-php-ext-install`, and `docker-php-ext-enable` to more easily install PHP extensions.

If your image is based on `ubuntu`, not `php`, you might find `docker-php-ext-install`, for example, on [github](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/master/docker-php-ext-install).

But since your `Dockerfile` is `FROM ubuntu`, I advise you to install php with `apt-get`:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt -yqq update
RUN apt -yqq install nginx iputils-ping
RUN apt-get install -y php php-fpm pdo-mysql php-mbstring
```

Do not forget to set up `nginx` to use php-fpm. To do so, I personally use a `start.sh` script, which starts `php-fpm` and `nginx` in the container:

```
php-fpm -D
nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

And in the `Dockerfile` I run the script. not `nginx`:

```
COPY start.sh /tmp/start.sh
CMD ["/tmp/start.sh"]
```

Comment: I'm marking your answer as a solution to this particular problem, but you cannot (or I don't know how) get specific PHP version using `apt-get` and because of that I used something other. But thanks!

Comment: I am a Fedora user myself, but as far as I know you can do `apt-get install <package name>=<version>` or at least `apt-get install -y php5.6`. If you google it, the solution will surely present itself.

Comment: How can I add helper scripts docker-php-ext-configure, docker-php-ext-install in my docker file ?

Comment: @flik copy-paste. From original project to yours.

Comment: I coppied scripts from https://github.com/flik/php/tree/master/7.0/stretch/cli and pasted in my docker file but getting error regarding some dependencies for execution.

Comment: @flik please consider opening a relevant question. This question is almost 2 years old and it makes no sense to provide help in comments. Opening a new question you at least would be able to provide more details on the matter of your problem, format your code and explain the details, which is impossible in the comments.