# Unable to install ext-mysqli in official php docker image

Tags: php, docker, mysqli

I am using the official php8 docker image and install my composer dependencies with

```
- composer install
```

My composer file requires :

```
    "ext-json": "*",
    "ext-mysqli": "*",
    "ext-curl": "*",
    "ext-zip": "*",
    "ext-simplexml": "*",
```

I have tried the apt  way of installing the extensions:

```
            - apt-get update && apt-get install -y php8.0-mysql            
            - docker-php-ext-enable ext-mysql
```

I recieve the following errors:

> Problem 1
> - Root composer.json requires PHP extension ext-mysqli * but it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mysqli extension.
> Problem 2
> - Root composer.json requires PHP extension ext-zip * but it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's zip extension.

> To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
> - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sodium.ini.
> Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-mysqli --ignore-platform-req=ext-zip --ignore-platform-req=ext-gd` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.

Can someone suggest a way to install these extensions as the official way does not seem to work for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37527960/3536236 ?

Comment: The https://stackoverflow.com/a/37527960/3536236 from Martin helped a lot. The simplest way to install the mysqli extension was with : 
 `- docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc)   mysqli`