# Pecl having trouble installing php redis in docker

Tags: php, docker, redis, pecl

I have set up a Docker environment for my symfony application.

One problem I'm facing is everytime docker runs `docker-php-ext-install redis` or `pecl install redis` I'll get error that says:

```
#0 2.161 #3 /usr/local/lib/php/OS/Guess.php(107): OS_Guess->parseSignature('Linux buildkits...')
#0 2.161 #4 /usr/local/lib/php/PEAR/Dependency2.php(109): OS_Guess->__construct()
#0 2.161 #5 /usr/local/lib/php/PEAR/Downloader.php(277): PEAR_Dependency2->__construct(Object(PEAR_Config), Array, Array, 4)
#0 2.161 #6 /usr/local/lib/php/PEAR/Downloader.php(556): PEAR_Downloader->getDependency2Object(Object(PEAR_Config), Array, Array, 4)
#0 2.161 #3 /usr/local/lib/php/OS/Guess.php(107): OS_Guess->parseSignature('Linux buildkits...')
#0 2.161 #4 /usr/local/lib/php/PEAR/Dependency2.php(109): OS_Guess->__construct()
#0 2.161 #5 /usr/local/lib/php/PEAR/Downloader.php(277): PEAR_Dependency2->__construct(Object(PEAR_Config), Array, Array, 4)
#0 2.161 #6 /usr/local/lib/php/PEAR/Downloader.php(556): PEAR_Downloader->getDependency2Object(Object(PEAR_Config), Array, Array, 4)
#0 2.161 #7 /usr/local/lib/php/PEAR/Downloader.php(458): PEAR_Downloader->analyzeDependencies(Array)
#0 2.161 #8 /usr/local/lib/php/PEAR/Command/Install.php(671): PEAR_Downloader->download(Array)
#0 2.161 #9 /usr/local/lib/php/PEAR/Command/Common.php(270): PEAR_Command_Install->doInstall('install', Array, Array)
#0 2.161 #10 /usr/local/lib/php/pearcmd.php(310): PEAR_Command_Common->run('install', Array, Array)
#0 2.161 #11 /usr/local/lib/php/peclcmd.php(32): require_once('/usr/local/lib/...')
#0 2.161 #12 {main}
#0 2.161   thrown in /usr/local/lib/php/OS/Guess.php on line 306
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pecl install redis" did not complete successfully: exit code: 255
```

My Dockerfile looks somthing like:

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm-buster

COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-config.ini

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    gnupg \
    g++ \
    procps \
    openssl \
    git \
    unzip \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libicu-dev  \
    libonig-dev \
    libxslt1-dev \
    acl \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    zip

RUN pecl install redis <-- fails here

(...)
```

I have been searching for this particular issue, but didn't find any solution.

I would be happy to hear something.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install extension for php via docker-php-ext-install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527803/how-to-install-extension-for-php-via-docker-php-ext-install)

Comment: @MarkusZeller The link you have provided didn't help me solve this issue.

Comment: So did you use `docker-php-ext-install` command to install the extension? It is especially made for PHP.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Yes that's exactly what I also tried to do. 
I have been looking into it, it looks like to be coused by my php.ini that I copy to docker conteiner at line 3.

Comment: You should put all that information into the question. You can edit it.