# I'm searching for the activation location of my PHP extension in my PHP Docker container

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, php-extension

When I check the activated extensions in my php Docker container, the output lists several PHP modules, such as Core, ctype, curl, and others.

the extensions appears to be deactivated In the php.ini file for example `;extension=curl`, and when I try to activate it (), I encounter the following error

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl'
> (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/curl
> (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/curl: cannot
> open shared object file: No such file or directory)

I'm just trying to figure out where this activation is happening.

am using `php:8.1.25-apache-bullseye`

Comment: You need to add "curl" into the `docker-php-ext-install` instruction

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install extension for php via docker-php-ext-install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527803/how-to-install-extension-for-php-via-docker-php-ext-install)

Comment: The extension is already active within my Docker image, so I don't need to activate it. 

I'm just trying to figure out where this activation is configured. In the php.ini file, the extension appears to be deactivated, and when I try to activate it (;extension=curl),
I encounter the error mentioned in my question.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, the source for for `docker-php-ext-install` is available on Github, for example at https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/master/8.1/bookworm/cli/docker-php-ext-install. Why do you need that file at all?

Comment: ok thx, i don't need all of them to be active all the time also i need to remove some of them

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Which extension do you want to disable, and why? What have you tried to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you try to use "curl" functions inside php scripts

You need to add "curl" into the `docker-php-ext-install` instruction. From your Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.1.25-apache-bullseye
WORKDIR /var/www/t3coredev

## Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
    libxml2-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libltdl-dev \
    libicu-dev \
    libmemcached-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    iputils-ping \
    vim \
    wget \
    curl \
    git \
    build-essential \
    libcurl4 \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install Composer manually
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

## Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    --with-freetype=/usr/include/ \
    --with-jpeg=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
    pdo \
    session \
    filter \
    mbstring \
    intl \
    fileinfo \
    gd \
    zip \
    xml \
    dom \
    curl \
    pdo_mysql

## install ImageMagick https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-imagemagick-on-debian-linux/
#RUN git clone https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick.git /usr/local/src/ImageMagick \
#    cd /usr/local/src/ImageMagick \
#    ./configure \
#    make \
#    make install \
#    sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib

RUN a2enmod alias \
    && a2enmod authz_core \
    && a2enmod deflate \
    && a2enmod expires \
    && a2enmod filter \
    && a2enmod headers \
    && a2enmod rewrite \
    && a2enmod setenvif
```

Once done, you should be able to run

```
docker build . -t myimagetag
```

Then to test if curl is enabled

```
docker run myimagetag php -r 'echo curl_exec(curl_init("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random"));'
```

That test curl for the php CLI usage

Comment: The extension is already active within my Docker image, so I don't need to activate it. I'm just trying to figure out where this activation is configured. In the php.ini file, the extension appears to be deactivated, and when I try to activate it (;extension=curl), I encounter the error mentioned in my question.

Comment: Thats because ini files loaded are into the directory /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d or /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d
Here you can see additionnal extensions loaded.
So the extension is named curl.so.


You should do "php -i" or a "phpinfo();"
It show details about configurations loaded

Comment: ok grat it helps thx