# PDO : Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver

Tags: php, pdo, odbc

I'm using odbc and XAMPP. I'm receiving the fatal error of could not find driver

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php:5 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(5): PDO->__construct('odbc:BEGIN') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 5

This is the code the error refering to :

```
$conn = new PDO ("odbc:BEGIN");
```

Is there any module that I should add to the php.ini like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2852997/6705667) or there are other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable those extensions in order to have ODBC PDO driver working

```
php_pdo.dll 
php_odbc.dll
php_pdo_odbc.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

After enabling those extension as @Sarhan said, we need to **restart** Apache in order for it to work.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @Far , i should have mentioned that