# How to issue "could not find driver" in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I create my project with Laravel 5.3 in localhost, after create I upload project in VPS, but after upload this error shows:

[image]

In `localhost`: 
`PHP` version is: 7.0,
`OS`: Ubuntu 16.04,

In `VPS`: 
`PHP` version is: 7.0, `OS`: Ubuntu server 16.04 and `Mysql` is not install (The other server's database).

.env file in VPS:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=192.168.19.51
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=flight
DB_USERNAME=*****
DB_PASSWORD=*****
```

Do I need to change the `PHP` or `VPS` or Laravel`?

**EDIT 1:**

`config/database.php`:

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

Comment: Can you show us what is in your config/database.php. More specifically under your "mysql" connection. Also there is no shame in putting `*****` over your database/username/password when posting them online :)

Comment: Hi @devk, my question is update :-)

Comment: I don't see any problems with either env or config. And I've never faced this problem before. Hopefully someone else will be able to help.

Comment: Did you say `mysql` is not installed on the VPS?

Comment: Hi @James , I create other VPS with ip `192.168.19.51` for DB.

Comment: @devk , I need install or enable `PDOException` in VPS?

Comment: Despite you're not using your VPS as the database - you might still need the driver for it http://stackoverflow.com/a/2852997/1739852

Comment: @James , Thank you i run this command: `apt-get install php7.0-mysql`

Comment: And it worked??

Comment: Yes, But this error code `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user... ` is show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP PDO Extension is not installed on VPS. Check this answer [PDOException “could not find driver”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2852997/1158777)

Just run on VPS

> sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql