# PDOException,could not find driver

Tags: php, html, laravel-5.4

I am trying to make a laravel and stucked when migration. when i enter php artisan migrate in terminal, showing PDOException error. attaching my screenshot of terminal and phpinfo.[image]

Comment: :~/xampp/blog$ php artisan migrate:install
 [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                         
  could not find driver (SQL: create table `migrations` (`id` int unsigned no  
  t null auto_increment primary key, `migration` varchar(191) not null, `batc  
  h` int not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)   
                                                                               

                         
  [PDOException]         
  could not find driver

Comment: just press the title to show image

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDOException “could not find driver”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)