# Yii2 Database Connection - PDOException

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, yii, yii2

I tried to change mysql to ms sql server dbms in yii but encounter PDO Exception, 
"Caused by: PDOException could not find driver". What is the issue there?

This is db.php file.

```
'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
'dsn' => 'sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=mydb',
'username' => 'myusername',
'password' => 'myps',
'charset' => 'utf8'
```

This is config.php.

```
'components' => [
    'db' => [
        'dsn' => 'sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=mydb',
    ],
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDOException “could not find driver”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)

Answer (score 3):

You need to install PDO driver for your database type.

*Before proceeding, make sure you have installed both the PDO PHP extension and the PDO driver for the database you are using (e.g. pdo_mysql for MySQL). This is a basic requirement if your application uses a relational database.*

Please refer these links for detail:

[Guide Start Databases - Configuring a DB Connection Section](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-databases.html)

[MSSQL PDO](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-mssql-pdo.html)