# could not find driver SQL but migrate works

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I deployed my code to server and migrated the database with command bellow:

```
php artisan migrate
```

And everything works fine.
But when I want to access to my url it throws the following exception:

```
could not find driver (SQL: select * from `...`)
```

[image: this is the image to the error page]
If it cannot find the driver then how it created the tables? Am I missing something. 
Also my database works fine when I run

```
php artisan serve
```

on my server and access that locally.

Comment: can you send me error number or code or pic.?

Comment: ok sir you upload error pic

Comment: Send me php code i try to run in my system

Comment: It is a laravel project. The php code works fine in development area. The problem is in other place I guess. If you could be more specific to send which part

Comment: pdo_mysql in phpinfo()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver

Comment: Sounds like the `.env` file on the server is set up to use a database driver that isn't installed. Check what connection type it uses on the server and make sure that driver is installed.

Comment: uncommenting pdo_mysql worked. But I didn't understand why it didn't throw any error while migrating the database. Don't they use the same driver?