# Illuminate\Database\QueryException and [PDOException] on Laravel Migration with Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to execute a migration on laravel but I get this message

```
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                         
  could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where t  
  able_schema = notes_bd and table_name = migrations) 
[PDOException]         
  could not find driver
```

This is the .env file ,the connection data is correct

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:BBhkGEzYaTMTLkDoOaWc1uxi0j29TMbhSJQbow0WaIc=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=notes_bd
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=secret
...
```

and the pdo extension is enabled on the server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver

Comment: where is your query code ?