# How to do I connect to a SQL Server instance from PHP 7 on an AWS Amazon Linux EC2 instance?

Tags: php, sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, php-7

I have Apache 2.4 and PHP 7 installed and working fine on an Amazon Linux AMI on AWS. From PHP, I can connect to MySQL DBs just fine, but now I need to connect to a SQL Server DB.

How do I do this? What's the PHP code I need to write and do I need to install additional PHP packages/modules to do this? I already have PDO installed and tried to use it, but the following code throws the following error:

```
$dsn = 'sqlsrv:dbname=db-name;host=aws-endpoint.rds.amazonaws.com';
$user = 'user-name';
$password = 'password';
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
```

Error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in /var/www/html/php-script-name.php
```

---

**Edit**: Adding to my question a bit, I ran a `yum search pdo` from the EC2 instance and got the following:

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
============================================================================================================= N/S matched: pdo ==============================================================================================================
php-ZendFramework-Db-Adapter-Pdo.noarch : Zend Framework database adapter for PDO
php-ZendFramework-Db-Adapter-Pdo-Mssql.noarch : Zend Framework database adapter for MS SQL PDO
php-ZendFramework-Db-Adapter-Pdo-Mysql.noarch : Zend Framework database adapter for MySQL PDO
php-ZendFramework-Db-Adapter-Pdo-Pgsql.noarch : Zend Framework database adapter for PgSQL PDO
php70-pdo-dblib.x86_64 : PDO driver Microsoft SQL Server and Sybase databases
php71-pdo-dblib.x86_64 : PDO driver Microsoft SQL Server and Sybase databases
php-pdo.x86_64 : A database access abstraction module for PHP applications
php54-pdo.x86_64 : A database access abstraction module for PHP applications
php55-pdo.x86_64 : A database access abstraction module for PHP applications
php56-pdo.x86_64 : A database access abstraction module for PHP applications
php70-pdo.x86_64 : A database access abstraction module for PHP applications
php71-pdo.x86_64 : A database access abstraction module for PHP applications

  Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
```

It seems like `php70-pdo-dblib.x86_64` is the plugin I want, so I ran `yum install` on it and my phpinfo now looks like the following:

[image]

I did restart Apache as well, but I still get the error noted above with the code noted above.

As such, I do not think that this is a duplicate of the question linked in the comments section.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDOException “could not find driver”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. You do in fact have to have `php70-pdo-dblib` installed and restart the server. However, my $dbn string was off. Specifically, `sqlsrv` needed to be changed to `dblib` and I added the port number `:1433` onto the end of the `host` part.

As such, the following code worked:

```
$dsn = 'dblib:host=aws-endpoint.rds.amazonaws.com:1433;dbname=db-name;';
$user = 'user-name';
$password = 'password';

try {

  $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

  $result = $dbh->query("SELECT * 
    FROM table-name;");

  foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo '<pre>';
      print_r($row);
    echo '</pre>';
  }

} catch (PDOException $e) {

  echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Microsoft SQL PHP driver.

Follow the instructions on this page:

[MSPHPSQL](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the official guide from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/php/rhel/) when you get to the point of installing unixODBC refer to this page to build an RPM and install it:

https://github.com/EreMaijala/unixODBC