# Artisan migrate --seed Error

Tags: php, linux, laravel, laravel-artisan, manjaro

When executing the php artisan migrate command --seed an error message is generated on the console, has anyone ever experienced this? Here is the message below:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                         
could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where 
table_schema = homestead and table_name = migrations)
```

following with

```
[PDOException]         
could not find driver
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDOException “could not find driver”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure pdo_mysql is installed.

In ubuntu: sudo apt install php-mysql