# Connect to mysql with php and view in web browser

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, connection

Trying to connect to a **remote mysql server** with php inserted into html.

I'm getting an error:

> could not find driver with the below code.

The mysql example in the link does not return anything.

What I want is to extract and save info plus edit, create tables through http.
How can I do that?

MySql version: 5.7.22-0ubuntu18.04.1
Php version: PHP Version 7.2.3-1ubuntu1

Source: [php pdo code](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

```
<?php
    //Database Credentials
    $host = 'localhost';
    $database = 'dbName';
    $username = 'userName';
    $password = 'userPassword';
     
    try {
      $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $username, $password); }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "did catch that! ";
        echo $e->getMessage(); }
     
    echo " #it works";

?>
```

Edit note:
Got it working after following Thomas Deutschländer advice.
Server is local and php is running on server, are going to view results/return from php in web page from local and remote net.

Some info:
Gained (viewed from php -m) after sudo apt-get install php-mysql:
mysqli
mysqlnd
pdo_mysql
(viewed from dpkg --get-selections | grep php)
php-mysql
php7.2-mysql
(viewed from dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql)
php-mysql
php7.2-mysql

Had previously:
PDO - viewed from php -m

Comment: "Note that you cannot perform any database functions using the PDO extension by itself; you must use a database-specific PDO driver to access a database server." http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDOException “could not find driver”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have installed php and the mysql-server properly, you have also to install the php mysql extension with

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysql
```

After that, you have the driver for mysqli and PDO.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> I'm trying to connect to a **remote** mysql server

This is at odds with the line of code that includes `$host = 'localhost';`.  The string `localhost` tells your database driver that the MySQL server is hosted on the same machine (aka IP address `127.0.0.1`) as the server the PHP is running on.

You need to replace `localhost` with the domain name or IP address of the actual MySQL server. Also, make sure that the server is configured to allow external communications. I doubt it is configured in such a way by default.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the PHP PDO extension installed: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php