# Error connecting to SQL Server database

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm having an error connecting to my database on another server since PHP.

Install the extension to connect, in my `phpinfo()` I can see it.

[image]

In my php code I execute the following:

```
if( sqlsrv_configure("WarningsReturnAsErrors", 0) === false)  
{  
    DisplayErrors();  
    die;  
}  else {
    echo sqlsrv_configure("WarningsReturnAsErrors", 0);
}
```

And what returns is a "1"

However, if I run:

```
$serverName = "MY.IP,1433";
$database = "my_database";
$uid = 'usr';
$pwd = '12345';
try {
    $conn = new PDO(
        "sqlsrv:server=$serverName;Database=$database",
        $uid,
        $pwd,
        array(
            //PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        )
    );
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    die("Error connecting to SQL Server: " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

I receive the error

> could not find driver

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver

Comment: did you install the driver ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/example-application-pdo-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: You have installed php_sqlsrv_.dll extension, but you need php_pdo_sqlsrv_.dll.