# PHP PDO Driver not found

Tags: php, pdo, apache2

I have issues with my PHP installation under Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I am getting the error: the driver is not found 1. I already tried the fix from the following post: [PDOException “could not find driver”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver) but it doesn't work. I am running Apache2 with a PHP7.2 Installation. If I run `phpinfo()` I can see, that it's 
"PHP Version 7.2.7-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1" 
and I can see the PDO extension and the pdo_mysql extension, so theoretically it should find the driver. Both states enabled. 
 The Script im calling:

```
<?php
include("sqlconnection.php");
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM reaktor WHERE reactorID = 1");
$result = $statement->execute();
$return = $statement->fetchAll();
echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

The sqlconnection.php:

```
<?php
  $serverName = "nw-system.de";
  $dbName = "openComputers";
  $username = "";
  $passwort = "";
  try{
    $pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$serverName ; Database=$dbName", $username, $passwort);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  }
  catch(Exception $e)
  {
    exit(print_r($e->getMessage()));
  }
?>
```

I have deleted the username and password on purpouse

 Any Ideas on how to fix this?
Kind regards
Jan

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php7.2-mysql` and `sudo phpenmod pdo_mysql` after that restart your apache.

Comment: @jagad89 - The OP states _"If I run phpinfo() ... I can see the PDO extension and the pdo_mysql extension"_

Comment: Tried that already

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Oh!! My bad

Comment: can you see those extensions in `php -m` output too?

Comment: When do you get the error message? Are you running your script through Apache or CLI?

Comment: @jagad88 Yes I can

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson Calling a PHP Script via Ajax

Comment: I do have it installed

Comment: Then I have no idea, unless the ajax request is calling some other URL on another server/setup. These things are pretty hard to debug from a distance...

Comment: @JanKrüger update your question with PHP source code.

Comment: @jagad89 I updated it.

Comment: your connection string starts with `sqlsrv`, are you using MSSQL? 
if yes, read [this](https://www.reich-consulting.net/support/developement/php-developement/install-php-sqlsrv-driver-on-linux/).
if you using MySQL change it to `mysql:`.

Comment: Yes that was it. Im using MySQL. I ripped that code out of another project that is using MsSQL. What a foolish mistake. Thx for the help.

Comment: Dangerous copy paste. Stay alert!! happy coding :)