# php artisan migrate - not running

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

When I try to run `php artisan migrate` I get it too. 
Pdo Okay also php up 7.1

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL:
>   select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel
>   and table_name = migrations) at
>   C:\wamp64\www\laralearn\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
>
> Exception trace:
>
> 1   PDOException::("could not find driver")
>         C:\wamp64\www\lara-learn\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
>
> 2
>   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=laravel",
>   "root", "", [])
>         C:\wamp64\www\lara-learn\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
>
> Please use the argument -v to see more details.

Comment: I was just about to post the same question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDOException “could not find driver”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)

Comment: Run `php -i` and check if the `pdo_mysql` driver is installed.

Comment: what laravel version you use ? make sure you configure correct setting for database connection.

Comment: laravel 5.7 - yes

Comment: pdo driver not value - how to set value(mysql) for pdo drivers??

Comment: In the php.ini file, make sure the `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` is uncommented. Then, restart IIS.