# Can't connect to mysql database with Doctrine in Symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to connect my `Symfony 4` application with my `mysql` database but I'm having some issues.

I have installed `doctrine` with these commands line: 
`composer require symfony/orm-pack` and `composer require symfony/maker-bundle --dev`. 
After that I have configured the `.env` to connect to my localhost mysql database with the correct user and password.

Then I create my `entity` class USER and I tried to migrate that `entity` to the database with the command line `php bin/console make:migration` but this error appear on my terminal:

> In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 106:
>                                                                An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 31:
>                               could not find driver
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 27:
>                               could not find driver

Every step I followed is from the `symfony 4`(https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html) documentation. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at this thread? may be the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver/2852997

Comment: Not exactly same issue, but reading in the comments I found my solution: `sudo apt-get install php-mysql`. Thanks @badger0053

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure your driver is installed.
For Ubuntu 16 and PHP7 use:

`sudo apt-get install php-mysql`

Comment: @HessianMad I think its helpful for the larger community to have answer in an actual answer rather than a comment. The question/comment may be overlooked without an answer