# Laravel throws QueryException: "could not find driver" using cpanel

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

I'm making a simple Laravel app for a friend.
I got access to their cpanel, made a subdomain, uploaded the app.
It seems to be working fine until I try to query the DB from web.php

```
Route::get('/', function (Product $p) {
    $p = $p -> all();
});
```

The above line throws an exception saying

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>
> could not find driver (SQL: select * from `products`)

The PDO extension is enabled

```
if (class_exists('PDO')) { 
    echo "installed"; 
} 
else { 
    echo "not installed"; 
}
```

echoes enabled.
Any help would be  greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDOException “could not find driver”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)