# PDOException::("could not find driver") PHP Configuration MySql

Tags: php, laravel, pdo

Just started exploring Laravel.

I created a fresh project from start. When trying to run php artisan migrate command I am getting this error:

```
  Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel and table_name
 = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\TestLaravelApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:665
    661|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    662|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    663|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    664|   



    catch (Exception $e) {
  > 665|             throw new QueryException(
    666|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    667|             );
    668|         }
669| 

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("could not find driver")
      C:\xampp\htdocs\TestLaravelApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=laravel", "root", "", [])
      C:\xampp\htdocs\TestLaravelApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

My database.php file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'laravel'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer body of commands than a typical key-value system
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [

        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
            'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_'),
        ],

        'default' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', 0),
        ],

        'cache' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', 1),
        ],

    ],

];
```

My .env file:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:CzpqNscMHgrAu1ctWWWrvj3x5dT7ak/NHFI774evggU=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Php Version:

PHP 7.3.10 (cli) (built: Sep 24 2019 11:59:22) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.10, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies

/**PHP.ini*/

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
; extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
extension_dir="C:/xampp/php/ext"

extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
;extension=php_ftp.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8_12c.dll  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=php_odbc.dll
;extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll
```

I have tried all possible solution present in stackoverflow.

may be I am missing something.

URL for php.ini file I am using: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ptnqax

[image: php.info]
Thanks

Comment: Check your `phpinfo` if the PDO MySQL driver is actually enabled.

Comment: Its enabled....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver

Comment: you've shared a phpinfo for php 7.1 but your cli php is 7.3. There's a good chance you're using a different version than what you're configuring,

Comment: yes That was the issue
Reverting back the changes which I did for .ini file at php installed location worked for me.

Dont know why downvote as i have just started into laravel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally was able to figure it out my self. While changing configuration in php.ini file which is in xampp folder I also modified the file in php installed location .ini file. reverting back the changes worked.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a module called `pdo_mysql`. Check in `php.ini` file

Try uncommenting this line from  `php.ini`. JUst remove `;` from that line save file and restart your server.

```
 extension=pdo_mysql
```

Try adding this line in `php.ini` file

```
 extension=php_pdo_mysql.so
```

Comment: [Pdo_mysql]
; If mysqlnd is used: Number of cache slots for the internal result set cache
; http://php.net/pdo_mysql.cache_size
pdo_mysql.cache_size=2000

; Default socket name for local MySQL connects.  If empty, uses the built-in
; MySQL defaults.
; http://php.net/pdo_mysql.default-socket
pdo_mysql.default_socket=

Comment: is this th eone

Comment: @Amit are you using xampp?

Comment: @ Prashant Yes. Xampp

Comment: @Amit then from xampp control panel you can find `php.ini` file on `config` tab in `apache` option. You just have click that option.

Comment: Sharing that file content as well

Comment: Updated my stackblitz.. php_conf.ini

Comment: Please have a look

Comment: @Amit check  update line to add in `php.ini` file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203107/discussion-between-amit-and-prashant-deshmukh).

Comment: I tried but didnt work