# PHP PDOException connection issue - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to run an existing Laravel application with "php artisan serve". Since the application have been developed with laravel 4.2, php 5.6 supported had to install php, apache separately in my local environment.

```
{"error":{"type":"PDOException","message":"could not find driver","file":"\/var\/www\/html\/PROJECT\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Database\/Connectors\/Connector.php","line":47}}
```

Can anyone tell how to fix this issue ? Am I missing any settings in the php.ini ?

Comment: Duplicated of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver ?

Comment: seems you are missing the driver needed for the database you are using ... what database are you trying to use?

Comment: it is mysql. I think I have installed all the necessary drivers. But still I am getting the above message.