# php artisan commands say a driver is missing

Tags: mysql, laravel, mysql-workbench, mamp, php-7

Somehow most of my php artisan commands report an error:

```
    C:\Projects\bapestore>php artisan migrate

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = bapestore and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at C:\Projects\bapestore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:669
    665|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    666|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    667|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    668|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 669|             throw new QueryException(
    670|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    671|             );
    672|         }
    673|

  1   C:\Projects\bapestore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDOException::("could not find driver")

  2   C:\Projects\bapestore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDO::__construct()
```

I just installed PHP7, Laravel, MAMP, MySQL Workbench locally on my Windows 10 to be able to practice more at home. (Lord, has that been an odyssee..) And now I am trying to connect my database, but the tutorial I follow uses a Mac OS.. so I can't follow the instructions there.

Can anyone understand that error?

Comment: Tell me if your phpinfo() shows that pdo_mysql is installed.

Comment: It says only: PDO

PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers =>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PDOException “could not find driver”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Using Google, tons of ways to resolve this can be found

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely missing a PHP extension. If you are able to locate your `php.ini` file, search for `extension=mysqli` or `extension=pdo_mysql` extensions. You may need to un-commment them to enable the extensions.

Comment: I've enabled `extension=mysqli` the other extension was already enabled. Still get the same error message

Answer (score 0):

Type in your terminal

```
php --ini
```

This command will tell the current path of your php.ini configuration file.

Uncoment the following lines in that file.

```
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

Comment: extension=pdo_mysql was already uncommented before I asked the question. There is no php_pdo... extension in my file.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Tried everything you said, and still get the same error message.

Comment: 1) In your .env file the code is DB_CONNECTION=mysql? 2) In your app/config/database.php is 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql')? 3) Did you put whitespaces between the word extension and the equal sign? Like this extension = php_pdo.dll?
extension = php_pdo_mysql.dll

Comment: Tell me if the command php -m shows that pdo_mysql is enabled.

Comment: Another possible change is first test extension_dir = "ext", if it not works, change to absolute path to something like extension_dir = "C:\php\ext" or extension_dir="C:\php".

Comment: I had to enable extension=pdo_mysql