# Symfony 5 fast track book bug when migrating databases

Tags: symfony, doctrine

This is my first step to symfony world, and I follow tutorial from Symfony fast track book. By executing the command below, my migration failed:

```
symfony new --version=5.0-3 --book guestbook --debug
```

Everything is OK expect "Migrating the database", this is the error:

[image]

Or symfony book:check-requirements says everything is OK.

[image]

For information: pdo_pgsql is already enabled in php.ini

Any trick to solve this issue?

**I have moved to PHP 7.3.12 version to solve my issue.**

**By staying with PHP 7.4.0 version, you cannot add property when you execute the command: php bin/console make:entity MyEntity**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PDOException “could not find driver”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)

Comment: I already have pdo_pgsql enabled. Command (php -m) shows me that it is well enabled. The link below does not answer my question but thanks anyway

Comment: Please share more details. When running the exact same command, I don't receive any of the errors

Answer (score 0):

I started Potencier's book two days ago. I faced several problems, which I have been able to solve, but I did not find this problem. I think you should give us more information. For example: What hardware are you using? What operating system? Where did the command giving the error run from? Did you run the command from Symfony CLI?

Comment: This issue is solved by downgrading to PHP 7.3.12 version. Before that I used PHP 7.4 on win 10 64bits. But now, I am facing another problem which is the use of EasyAdmin. I do not know if the book is updated.