# Laravel could not find driver Cpanel

Tags: php, laravel, syntax-error, cpanel, web-deployment

I deployed my Laravel project on Cpanel but there's an error "could not find driver(SQL)"

I'm using Mysql database in Cpanel, and I have checked pdo_mysql in PHP extension.

but when I looked on

`phpinfo();` and find `pdo_mysql`, the result is 0/0

How to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what are the .env variables for you database connection?

Comment: DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=local
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=[DB_DATABASE](correct)
DB_USERNAME=[DB_USERNAME](correct)
DB_PASSWORD=[DB_PASSWORD](correct)

Comment: Did you enable pdo, pdo_mysql and pdo_sqlite ? I have mysqlnd checked too on my cpanel php settings. (not sure if thats needed)

Comment: yes, it's checked on my PHP Extension. but still I have the same error.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try to research your problem before posting a question. I searched for your exact error message, and found many answers, [example1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2852748/6089612).  I searched for "*enable PDO cpanel*" and found many more answers.  If you have already seen those and tried the posted solutions, and are still having problems, update your question and describe what you tried, and what happened.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PDOException “could not find driver”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)

Comment: thank you for comment. I already search that, and after hours and hours of searching of solutions still not work for me and here I am, hehe,

Comment: If you have already seen those and tried the posted solutions, and are still having problems, update your question and describe what you tried, and what happened.  How can anyone help you if you don't tell us what you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your reply. The culprit is my PHP version which is 7.3. then when I change it to 7.4 out of nowhere. It works like magic.

I change my `.htaccess` in Cpanel from

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php4|php5|php7|php3|php2|php|phtml)$">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-alt-php73
</FilesMatch
```

to

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php4|php5|php7|php3|php2|php|phtml)$">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-alt-php74
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed cpanel php version and this problem is solved.for laravel 10 and i changed php 8.2 to php 8.1