# I get PDOException when I try php artisan cache:clear

Tags: php

What should I do?

PHP8.2.13(cli)
Windows(WSL) Ubuntu20.04
Composer version 2.2.0

```
$ php artisan cache:clear

   PDOException 

  could not find driver

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70
     66▕         if (class_exists(PDOConnection::class) && ! $this->isPersistentConnection($options)) {
     67▕             return new PDOConnection($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
     68▕         }
     69▕
  ➜  70▕         return new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
     71▕     }
     72▕
     73▕     /**
     74▕      * Determine if the connection is persistent.

      +10 vendor frames 
  11  [internal]:0
      Krlove\EloquentModelGenerator\TypeRegistry::__construct()

      +15 vendor frames 
  27  [internal]:0
      Illuminate\Container\

      Container::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
```

Comment: "What should I do?" Install the missed extension, maybe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PDOException “could not find driver”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)

Comment: @hassan Sorry, I have only SQLServer.

Comment: Shouldn't it still work?

Answer (score 0):

PHP cannot find the appropriate database driver to connect to your database.

1. Install the PDO Extension for Your Database:

- For MySQL: Install the pdo_mysql extension.
- For PostgreSQL: Install the pdo_pgsql extension.

2. Ensure the appropriate extension is enabled in your php.ini file.

- For MySQL: extension=pdo_mysql
- For PostgreSQL: extension=pdo_pgsql

3. Restart your web server.

Comment: Thank you sir, but I have SQLServer only.
And I have a question. What do you mean "Restart my web server".

Comment: If you are using SQL Server, you can also install the PDO extension for **pdo_sqlsrv**.

Comment: Restarting your web server means restarting Apache or Nginx.

Comment: In the PHP CLI, changes such as installing PHP extensions take effect immediately, so there is no need to restart the web server.
However, in a web server environment, a restart is required to apply the changes.

Comment: Okay, I have PHP CLI. Maybe, I got pdo_sqlsrv already. But I still get PDOException.

Comment: Sorry, I try some commands and I get new error message!
SQLSTATE[HYT00]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
What's happen?

Comment: Maybe the database is configured incorrectly: Check the Laravel .env file for the correct database settings (e.g. DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DB_DATABASE, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD). Make sure these details are correct and match your SQL Server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted scripts section in composer.json.

```
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
},
```