# Create a database in Symfony

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine

I got the following error when I try to create a database by the terminal :

```
`PS D:\gestion\gestionprojet> php bin/console doctrine:database:create

Could not create database `gestionprojet` for connection named default
An exception occurred in the driver: could not find driver`
```

I changed my .env.dev.local by this :

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/gestionprojet?serverVersion=5.7
```

Do you have any idea of what is happening ?

Do you have any idea of what is happening ?

It's my first time creating a Database

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PDOException “could not find driver”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the PDO driver. If your are using MySQL, make sure your php.ini file contains this uncommented line:
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll