PHP connection to server failed in Visual Studio Code
I'm having trouble with connecting my PHP to a server so I can use a database.
First I've tried this code. But this gives me the message: "could not find driver".
 <?php
        $hostname = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "localhost";

       try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS myDBPDO";
            $conn->exec($sql);
            echo "Database created successfully<br>";

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            global $sql;
            echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
        }
?>

Then I tried something else.
<?php
        $hostname = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "localhost";

        $mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
        echo "hello1";
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
          }
        echo "hello2";
        

        echo "connected succesfully";
        $mysqli->close();
?>

When I serve my website I can't see the html that is below this code. So I tried with echo "hello" to get the problem:  $mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
Can someone help me to get the connection?
By the way I'm just started a fiew weeks ago with PHP and I don't know really much. I'm still learning a lot!

What does your phpinfo show for PDO/mysqli? Do you intend to use PDO or mysqli? Sounds like your system doesnt have mysql driver enabled, and the error handling for mysqli is not configured correctly so you dont get the same fatal error message there.

Did you install a MySQL Server? You dont actually tell us that? Or maybe a mariaDB server? If you did, did you start the server? So much info has to be assumed here that an answer is just going to be a guess

Welcome to SO.  Did you try searching for your error?  Chances are you are not the first to hit this problem, and chances are there are many answers here on SO already.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver

Stick with PDO, but please find a better tutorial. This is absolutely not how you connect to a database. Both examples have serious issues. Ideally, you should use a framework such as Laravel and not do it yourself.

It looks like you are using some really bad tutorial. I highly encourage you to find something better. If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo & https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection. Here are some good video tutorials https://youtu.be/2eebptXfEvw & https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVbEyFZKgqk&list=PLr3d3QYzkw2xabQRUpcZ_IBk9W50M9pe-

What platform are you using for development? eg Xampp, Wamp etc.
Make sure your MySQL server is running and port 3306 (the port MySQL uses) is open. I only use Xampp but you'll find access to MySQL in other platforms' control panels and you need to make sure the service is running before trying to create a database.
In your example, you've called the database localhost - you'd probably want to change this to a name more akin to what information your database is going to hold.
You might also find using a PHP framework (eg Laravel) a better choice for creating PHP apps as you won't have to create connections, functions and many features from scratch. Here's a couple of links that might help you and happy coding!
Xampp - https://www.apachefriends.org/
Laravel - https://laravel.com/

Your answer contains a lot of misinformation. Xampp is not a platform, it's just a collection of tools and the question author didn't mention anything about using xampp. The error message has nothing to do with the port. localhost is a perfectly fine way of connecting to a database.

Xampp is advertised as a platform. The OP didn't mention that they were using any tools at all, so I had to make an assumption. The error message said it 'could not find driver', now if port 3306 isn't accessible because it's either blocked or no MySQL server is running, there is a chance that error could come up. Using localhost as a database name is like using websites as a folder name and putting all your websites in there with no folders to differentiate them. I'm just trying to help them out.

"could not find driver" means that the specific PDO driver was not enabled. It has nothing to do with connectivity to the actual database server

I've seen that error myself when it can't connect to the database albeit in older versions of PHP when I used to use a similar method to the OP when connecting to the database, one of which was on a dedicated server where the port wasn't opened (ok, it was around 20 years ago). I was trying to steer the OP into using a PHP framework which I see you did yourself, so I don't agree with your summation that my answer contained "a lot of misinformation".
